# Left Alignment of footnotesize

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

I am trying to display the note under a figure left aligned. However if the note is more than one line the latter line is centered. If the note only contains one line it is displayed as below. Is there a way to "left align" the note ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Test dokument.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[]{lrem} %use some plac eholder 
\footnotesize {This is a note \par}.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotesize` (like all size commands) does not take an argument so your input is the same as `\footnotesize This is a note` also it has no affect at all on alignment, by default it would be justified, but if you have specified centering somewhere it will not change that, it just changes the size.

Comment: Thank you. What would be away to get a left aligned note ?

Comment: Try adding a \par (or blank line) between the image and text.  \caption does.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit hard to understand as `\footnotesize` has no affect on alignment and text is justified (so aligned at the left edge) by default.

Perhaps you are just missing the paragraph end after the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Test dokument.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[]{example-image} %use some plac eholder 
\footnotesize

This is a note.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```